# Using discriminant to prove that there are real solutions to a quadratic

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, discriminant

Question:

> Prove that there are two solutions of the equation $x^2 + kx = 3 - k $

The obvious solution would be finding the value of $b^2 - 4ac$

$x^2 + kx + k - 3=0$

$b^2 - 4 ac$

=$k^2 - 4(1)(k-3)$

=$k^2 - 4k + 12$

From here, $b^2 - 4ac$ have a algebraic value. If it is a constant, I would already be able to prove that the equation have $2$ real roots for every value of "$k$". So, how do I go about doing this question when I can't get $b^2 - 4ac$ to be a constant value?

Comment: Note that $k^2-4k+12=(k-2)^2+8$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picking up from where you left off, $$k^2 - 4k + 12 \equiv (k-2)^2 + 8 \geq 0 +8  > 0$$

since squares are *non-negative*. Then it follows that your discriminant is positive for all values of $k \in \mathbb{R}$ and hence the quadratic equation always has two roots.

Comment: Ohhh.... One thing I had noticed too is that $k^2 - 4k + 12$ no matter what value of "k" I choose, I get a positive nunber.

Comment: Yep, the technique of completing the square to show that an expression is always positive comes in useful *a lot*.